# Getting 404 error in api request with ASP.NET Core and Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm testing my ASP.NET Core APIs with Swagger. Everything is ok but I am new with swagger and apis.

I'm getting the following error. I'm setting a breakpoint in the first line, but it can not be reached.

> Error: 404 Response Headers: content-length: 0   date: Wed, 10 Oct
>   2018 17:02:20 GMT   server: Kestrel   status: 404   x-powered-by:
>   ASP.NET   x-sourcefiles:
>   =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcaWNsb3VcRG9jdW1lbnRzXFZpc3VhbCBTdHVkaW8gMjAxN1xyZXBvc19naXRfc291cmNlXGJhY2tlbmRfY3NoYXJwX3dpdGhfbG9jYXRpb25zXGJhY2tlbmRfY3NoYXJwXEJyaW8uTG9jYXRpb24uQXBpXGFwaVxzdWJ1cmJzXDEyMzQ1?=

This is my action method. I'm trying to get a collection of Suburbs by ZipCode:

```
        [HttpGet("{zipCode}")]
        [Produces(typeof(List<SuburbViewModel>))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSuburbByZipCodeAsync(string zipCode, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            try
            {
                if (await _manager.GetSuburbByZipCodeAsync(zipCode, ct) == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                var results = await _manager.GetSuburbByZipCodeAsync(zipCode, ct);

                Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results));

                return new ObjectResult(results);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex);
            }
        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: what is url /route being used?

Comment: @mvermef this one:   https://localhost:44354/api/suburbs/12345

Comment: can you post startup.cs code related to routes and the class definition of `suburbs`

Comment: @mvermef hey man, thanks... it was de url as you said, this was my fix
[HttpGet("GetByZipCode/{zipCode}")]... then a did the request to that url and it worked fine

Comment:  good to hear